# Symfony2 embedded forms and database duplicates

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, duplicates

I've got a form **UserType** related to the entity *User*.
This form calls another form : **CityType**

```
<?php

namespace ...\SiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('city', new CityType(), array('label' => false))
                ->add(...);
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FindBack\SiteBundle\Entity\User',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }
    // ...
}
```

The *User* associated table looks like :

```
id | city_id | ...
---|---------|-----
1  | 1       | ...
2  | 1       | ...
3  | 2       | ...
```

Here is **CityType** :

```
<?php

namespace FindBack\SiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FindBack\SiteBundle\Entity\City',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'city';
    }
}
```

So when I create *User* through **UserType** form, a new *City* is created.
If I create *User* twice with the same city name (ie: Marseille), my database will look like :

```
id  name
--|----------
1 | Marseille
2 | Marseille
3 | Paris
...
```

So there's a duplicate and I want to avoid it !
How can I proceed ? I tried to set an unique constraint to the *name* field of the *City* table but when I want to create another *User*, a **"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Marseille' for key 'name'** is thrown by Symfony2. It seems logic.

Do have I to check in the **controller** associated to *User* if there's already a city named *"Marseille"* in the database, and then associate the existant *City* to my *User* ?

Comment: Why don't you provide a solution where cities are already inserted into database?

Comment: @DonCallisto I'm not sure to understand what you mean... I'm not going to populate my database with all the cities from France !

Comment: So, if I'm going to populate your field with "city: the moon rocket" will you accept it?

Comment: @DonCallisto In fact, the city name is automatically filled by Google Places (the user types a place in the google places autocomplete field. Then I get back the city value and populate the city name field thanks to JQuery). But it doesn't matter, that's not the problem.

Comment: So if you accept "standard names" (so from google places) you have to verify before if the city was already into db and then do the proper actions

Comment: @DonCallisto Yep, that's why I asked a question on StackOverflow. I'm wondering how to do it

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need:

- a controller where you'll post your form
- a repository for your city entity

This is only an example as I don't know pretty much nothing about your application:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function registerUserAction(Request $request) {
  [...]
  $cr = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('CityRepository');
  [...]
  $user = new User();
  $form = $this->createForm(new $form(...), $user);
  $form->bind($request);
  //get the field from form
  $cn = $request->get('city_name');
  //search for a pre existent entity
  $city = $cn->findOneByCityName($cn);
  if($city) {
    $user->setCity($city);
  }
  if($form->isValid()){
    [...]
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like a workaround, i'm quite surprised Symfony2 doesn't provide another way to do it. Moreover, if I want to check name and twelve other fields, do have I to repeat the process for all of theses ?

Comment: @peltho: you can define your own constraint on form fields and let symfony2 check them for you (with `->isValid()` method). But this specific case is different as you won't only check but make some other actions upon that check...